Paradoxical generic trait syntax not in the Rust book (Actix)
How are generic types S and B supplied in Actix middleware Transform trait implementation?
pub struct SayHi;

// Middleware factory is `Transform` trait
// `S` - type of the next service
// `B` - type of response's body
impl<S, B> Transform<S, ServiceRequest> for SayHi
where
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static,
{
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type InitError = ();
    type Transform = SayHiMiddleware<S>;
    type Future = Ready<Result<Self::Transform, Self::InitError>>;

    fn new_transform(&self, service: S) -> Self::Future {
        ready(Ok(SayHiMiddleware { service }))
    }
}


My understanding is that the Transform trait will only implemented for SayHi when the conditions in the where clause are met, but SayHi itself doesn't carry any generic parameters.

The generics S (service type) and B (response body type) are used only within the impl block.

When and how are S and B actually supplied? I don’t see anywhere for the programmer to provide these types explicitly. They can be inferred via usage of new_transform if the right kind of S is supplied, but that doesn't make sense...

The new_transform method doesn’t have generic placeholders, and it seems like we can’t pass the types at that point because the method wouldn't be visible until it meets the constraints (bounds?), creating a paradox.


The code sample is presumably correct and from here: https://actix.rs/docs/middleware


The generics S (service type) and B (response body type) are used only within the impl block.

is straight up wrong. S is used as parameter to the trait Transform<S, ServiceRequest>. B is constrained by S with S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,, it's an associated type of S: Service so there is exactly one B for every S: Service<ServiceRequest, …>.
You can provide S with fully qualified function syntax:
<SayHi as Transform<YourService, ServiceRequest>>::new_transform(&SayHi, service);

or let it be inferred from the parameter you pass to it as a method:
let service: YourService = todo!();
SayHi.new_transform(service);

